# get directive attribute defined in HTML in directive controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I am creating a custom controller where I want to get directive attributes in controllers . Here what I have done so far but I am not able to get the attribute value .

**HTML Code :**

```
<my-text name="tester"></my-text>
```

**Angular code :**

```
app.directive('MyText', function() {
   var controller = ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        console.log($scope.name)
        $scope.text = $scope.name
      }];
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
      name: '='
    },
    controller: controller,
    template: 'Name: {$ text $}'
  };
});
```

you can see I have defined an attribute in HTML `name` have value `tester` I want to get this value in directive controller so that I can do some calculation on this and show result in `template` . Its just a demo what I am trying to do but in the end I'll send $http request to backend (attribute values in POST) and show response in template HTML.

Any suggestion where I am wrong ?

Note : I am using this `{$ var $}` syntax in angular because I am overwriting angular default syntax since I am using Python /Django as backend and both have similar syntax

Comment: Looking at the directive usage in html code. You should declare your directive as 'myText' rather than 'MyText'.

Comment: @Bibin typo mistake , anyway Razvan answer worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a demo [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LLPD4JOdkkTf07xdU7oI?p=preview)

You should update your directive like this:

```
app.directive('myText', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {
      name: '='
    },
    controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs){
      console.log($attrs.name)
      $scope.text = $attrs.name;
    },
    template: 'Name: {{text}}'
  };
});
```

Comment: One more question what if in `name` attribute of HTML we want to use dynamic value which then get by directive see [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/LLPD4JOdkkTf07xdU7oI?p=preview) I ahve modified your plunker

Comment: This is the same plunker

Comment: [new_plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JZvoC7mkVD0fookdmFeC?p=preview) check this , here I have define new_name which will used in directive HTML so that directive ctrl can get that and update but new_name is not rendering , I think bec before new_name can render `directive` already got render

Comment: just replace the `$attrs` in controller with `$scope`

Comment: yes , it works . Means for dynamic vars use $scope otherwise $attrs

Comment: Well yes. $attrs evaluates the attribute and leaves it as it is, while $scope works like a watch, updating the value with every change (dynamic data in your case)

Comment: If I'll use `ng-click` in appended HTML and click function is created in main controller will that function work ?

Comment: It should but its not working [check here](http://plnkr.co/edit/moCTBX45YxvCtucLwfRv?p=preview)

Comment: That is because you have scope defined on your controller. You can call the function in the scope and pass it in the html. [Here is how](http://plnkr.co/edit/XCsUU7hVYCdNGF75Chn7?p=preview)

Comment: yes, but this way I cannot access parms in `click_me()` passed in `onClick()`

Comment: You have to pass the params in `click_me()` in `html`

Comment: My html is based on directive controller so I have to pass params in directive HTML

Comment: Is there any way to access controller scope outside its directive or in  other controller so that I can use my ng-click function result in project HTML